# orientdb query linklist too slowly

Tags: orientdb

I have tow class: NOrder and NPassenger, relationship 1 : n, so NOrder has a filed named "passengers",whose type is linklist.

I want to select NOrder by NPassenger's field "passengerName",
I used sql

```
select from NOrder where 'John' in passengers.name
```

the NOrder ducuments count is 3 millon, this sql works too slowly, how can I do it?

thanks a lot

Comment: What version of OrientDb are you using ?
How many NPassenger document do you have in your database ?

Comment: thanks.
orientdb version is 2.1.11, NOrder document count is 2,996,396, NPassenger  4,247,524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert an index on the field *name* of the class *NPassenger*.
You can use this query

```
select expand(distinct(rid)) from (FIND REFERENCES (select from NPassenger where name = "John"))
```

Let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, "find references #49:9484", this sql is also slow.  I'm looking for other ways

Comment: Am confused -- is marked at the correct answer, but your comment says its not. What this the solution?